# How to set a Custom Image as ViewController Background

Tags: swift, path, background, uiimageview

I have created a button that allows me to set an image from the camera roll as the `ViewController` background (`imageView` is the background view), but I need to save it and reload it when `ViewController` loads.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var backgroundSelectionView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func imageButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            imageView.image = image
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I think I should use paths (I read it somewhere but I don't know how to do that since I can't find anything). Could you provide advice on how to save and load a CUSTOM image (not a specific one that you manually select and import in your code, I can already do that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

The easiest way to do this would likely be to save the image to disk once you have picked it and restore it when `ViewController` loads.

To save the image, use `FileManager` and save to the app's document storage:

```
/// Saves a background image to disk
/// - Parameter image: The background image to save to disk
/// - Returns: true if successful, false otherwise
func saveBackgroundImage(image: UIImage) -> Bool {

    // make sure that the image can be transformed into data (assuming PNG)
    guard let data = image.pngData() ?? imageView.image?.pngData() else {
        return false
    }

    // ensure that you can write to the document director
    guard let directory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, 
                                                   in: .userDomainMask).first else {
        return false
    }

    // write the file
    do {
        try data.write(to: directory.appendingPathComponent("backgroundImage.png")!)
        return true
    } catch {   
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }
}
```

Now, you need a way to retrieve the file:

```
/// Retrieves the saved background image
/// - Returns: The background image from disk if it exists, or nil
func getSavedBackgroundImage() -> UIImage? {
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, 
                                          in: .userDomainMask).first {
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: URL(fileURLWithPath: dir.absoluteString).appendingPathComponent("backgroundImage.png").path)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Inside your `imagePickerController(picker: didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)` method, when you set the image on `imageView`, save the background image by calling `self.saveBackgroundImage(image: image)`. If you are not checking the boolean that is returned from `saveBackgroundImage(image:)`, then call it as follows:

```
let _ = self.saveBackgroundImage(image: image)
```

to prevent a "Result unused" warning.

Now, implement your `viewDidLoad`, which is where you will attempt to load the image:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if let backgroundImage = self.getSavedBackgroundImage() {
        // set the background image on the `imageView`
        self.imageView.image = backgroundImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am just getting a few errors because I guess the isn't swift 4 and I'm not sure about how to convert them... the first one is in: `guard let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) ?? UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else { return false }`              and since I saw something similar to this on udemy I guessed I had to change  `UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)` in `imageView.image!.pngData()` but I guess it's wrong... anyway I still can't figure out the first part. and then in my button it says "Result of call to 'saveBackgroundImage(image:)' is unused" @LeejaySchmidt

Comment: I did this  `guard let data = image.pngData() ?? imageView.image!.pngData() else {
            return false
        }` and it works but I'd like to know if it's correct... and How can I fix the one in the button?

Comment: For safety, you might want to make it `imageView.image?.pngData()`, since it is technically possible for you to null-coalesce and still have a `nil` image in `imageView`.

Comment: To address the issue with `Result of call to 'saveBackgroundImage(image:)' is unused`, if you are not checking if the image was saved or not, you can just call it as follows: `let _ = self.saveBackgroundImage(image: image)`. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Please set backgroundImage as below,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    assignbackground()
}

func assignbackground(){
        let background = UIImage(named: backgroundImage)

        var imageView : UIImageView!
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        imageView.contentMode =  UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = background
        imageView.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageView)
    }
```

Please user remaining code as it is as @Leejay Schmidt's code

Comment: Why do I have to do this? I want the button to set the image, my code works pretty fine (except for the errors I got with the implementation of the new code that I am trying to solve)...